# Hierarchical graph using networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx, hierarchical

I want to draw a Hierarchical graph and i thought to use `networkx`.

Data I use :

[image: Screenshot of data]

The graph I want:

[image: Drawing of graph]

Based on the common element in rows I used different code but there is no result.